# Visual Basic - Adding two binary numbers

Tags: vb.net, binary, addition

Hi im new on here and in coding in general. I've been working on this code for adding two binary numbers together, individually the parts work but combined the don't. If anyone could help me with a solution for this I would be very grateful. Also if it could be shortened that would help as well, Thanks.

```
Class Form1

    Dim intNum1 As Integer
    Dim intNum2 As Integer
    Dim intNum3 As Integer

    Public Function BinaryToDecimalA(ByRef Binary As String) As Integer
        Dim BinaryNumA As Integer
        Dim BitCountA As Short

        For BitCountA = 1 To Len(Binary)
            BinaryNumA = BinaryNumA + (CDbl(Mid(Binary, Len(Binary) - BitCountA + 1, 1)) * (2 ^ (BitCountA - 1)))
        Next BitCountA
        BinaryToDecimalA = BinaryNumA

    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        intNum1 = (BinaryToDecimal((TextBox1.Text)))

    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

        If Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) And Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If

        TextBox1.MaxLength = 3
    End Sub
    Public Function BinaryToDecimal(ByRef Binary As String) As Integer
        Dim BinaryNum As Integer
        Dim BitCount As Short

        For BitCount = 1 To Len(Binary)
            BinaryNum = BinaryNum + (CDbl(Mid(Binary, Len(Binary) - BitCount + 1, 1)) * (2 ^ (BitCount - 1)))
        Next BitCount
        BinaryToDecimal = BinaryNum

    End Function

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        intNum2 = (BinaryToDecimal((TextBox2.Text)))

    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress

        If Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) And Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If

        TextBox2.MaxLength = 3
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        intNum1 = Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text)

        intNum2 = Integer.Parse(TextBox2.Text)

        intNum3 = intNum1 + intNum2

    End Sub

    Private Sub intNum3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxAns.TextChanged

        Dim i As Long, x As Long, bin As String
        Const maxpower = 7
        TextBoxAns.Enabled = False
        bin = ""
        x = Val(intNum3)

        If x > 2 ^ maxpower Then
            MsgBox("Number must be no longer than " & Str$(2 ^ maxpower))
            TextBoxAns.Text = ""
        End If

        If x < 0 Then bin = bin + "1" Else bin = bin + "0"

        For i = maxpower To 0 Step -1
            If x And (2 ^ i) Then
                bin = bin + "1"
            Else
                bin = bin + "0"
            End If
        Next
        TextBoxAns.Text = bin
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `dim a As Integer = Convert.ToInt32("101010", 2) + Convert.ToInt32("1000101", 2)`

Answer (score 0):

This should work - 
Not my code (reference http://www.bigresource.com/VB-Converting-a-number-to-its-binary-number-uDbSei3kPM.html) but it works !

Public Function BinaryAddition(ByVal A As String, ByVal B As String) As String

Dim curA As Currency

Dim curB As Currency

Dim curResult As Currency

```
curA = BinToDec(A)
```

curB = BinToDec(B)

```
curResult = (curA + curB) ' Mod (2 ^ 32)

BinaryAddition = DecToBin(curResult)
```

End Function

Private Function DecToBin(curDec As Currency) As String

Dim strTemp As String

Dim i As Integer

```
i = 31

Do While i >= 0
    If curDec >= (2 ^ i) Then
        strTemp = strTemp & "1"
        curDec = curDec - (2 ^ i)
    Else
        strTemp = strTemp & "0"
    End If

    i = i - 1
Loop

DecToBin = strTemp
```

End Function

Comment: Thanks for the code but I realy need it to be based on the code I have created above.

Answer (score -1):

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the first binary number, then enter the second binary number")
        Dim num As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine, 2)
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(num + Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine, 2), 2))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```